# How to update Visual Studio's NPM?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm

I navigated to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External
```

And has opend a command prompt as Administrator with this command

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Then I issued this command:

```
npm -v
```

Result: **1.4.9**

Shouldn't it be [3.10.8](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.10.8)?

---

This is my output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External>npm -v
1.4.9

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External>npm install npm@latest -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\npm -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@3.10.8 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\node_modules\npm

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External>npm -v
1.4.9
```

---

I basicly want to upgrade, because I have [problems with some references in tinymce](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2942)

Answer (score 6):

Try these steps-

1. Upgrade nodejs from here - https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Upgrade npm using - `npm install -g npm`
3. Check npm version using - `npm -v`

Also, you can ran "where" to see where (and how many) npm was installed - `where npm`

See if this helps.